# Dynamically change JSTree sort order

Tags: jstree

I'm using JSTree to display a small Windows Explorer-like appearance, everything is perfect but I have to implement sorting option also, is there anyway that I can have my tree sorting order dynamically changed? For example I can have a button that allows user to sort contents based on name (asc or desc), size, change date or even type. How can I perform it?
I think there is something wrong with JSTree sort plugin, or at least I cannot understand how it works!

This is what I do in order to change sort based on user interaction:

```
treeInst = $('#divWindowsExplorer').jstree(true);
var root = treeInst.get_node('j1_1');
$.jstree.defaults.sort = function (a, b) {
    return this.get_text(a) < this.get_text(b) ? -1 : 1;
};
$("#divWindowsExplorer").jstree(true).sort(root, true);
$("#divWindowsExplorer").jstree(true).redraw_node(root, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with sort options.

```
  $("#plugins5").jstree({
     "plugins" : [ "sort" ],
     'sort' : function(a, b) {
        // you can do custom sorting here
        // based on your user action you can return 1 or -1
        // 1 show on top -1 for show bottom 
    }
  });
```

For more info [click here](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.sort)

Comment: Yes I have this in my intialization, but the problem is that I want to change the sort logic based on user interaction, for example change from name ascending to name descending, how should I perform it?

Comment: Yes, I've already visited the above link. I've updated my question, plz take a look.

Comment: I think (selector).jstree(tree).sort(root, true) does actually nothing! Why?

Answer (score 0):

root node doesn't work when we call sort, I did sort my tree dynamically by calling sort and redraw_node function with the id of the first node of my tree instead of root.
Hope this is helpful.